# Alternative to GROUP BY CUBE in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to do a `GROUP BY CUBE()` with 8 different elements in Snowflake but based on the documentation, "*Snowflake allows up to 7 elements (equivalent to 128 grouping sets) in each cube*".

This is a limitation for one of the queries I need to run. The basic form of the query looks like

```
SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H
FROM (
    SELECT '1' AS A, '2' AS B, '3' AS C, '4' AS D, '5' AS E, '6' AS F, '7' AS G, 8 AS H
  ) SUB
GROUP BY CUBE(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H);
```

If column H is removed, it works just fine. But when I add H to the query, I get

> SQL compilation error: Number of grouping sets (256) exceeds maximum number of grouping sets allowed (128)

What would be the way to go to get the same results of a `GROUP BY CUBE` with 8 elements? I did some research and it looks like `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS` could work but there's still the 128 grouping sets limit in the same query block.

Comment: (what is the end goal for having this cube?)

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I need to get all the possible combinations of A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H. Maybe there's some other way to do it besides the `union all` solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can produce the 2^8 combinations by the union of two operations: One cube with `GROUP BY CUBE(A,B,C,D,E,F,G), H` -- and one without H, and make it null.

```sql
with data as (
  SELECT '1' AS A, '2' AS B, '3' AS C, '4' AS D, '5' AS E, '6' AS F, '7' AS G, 8 AS H
)

SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H
FROM data
GROUP BY CUBE(A, B, C, D, E, F, G), H
union all
SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, null
FROM data
GROUP BY CUBE(A, B, C, D, E, F, G)
```

You can prove this with less combinations:

```sql
SELECT A, B, C
FROM data
GROUP BY CUBE(A, B), C
union all
SELECT A, B, null
FROM data
GROUP BY CUBE(A, B)
```

You can see that it gives equivalent results to `GROUP BY CUBE(A,B,C)`.

Answer (score 0):

A brute force method is `union all`:

```
select null as a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h
from t
group by cube (b, c, d, e, f, g, h)
union all
select a, null as b, c, d, e, f, g, h
from t
group by cube (a, c, d, e, f, g, h)
union all
. . .
```

This is feasible for 8 columns.  It gets cumbersome if you have any more.

If you are just use `cube` to generate rows, there might be simpler ways to accomplish the same thing.